# How to Remove Black Rectangle on Window Resize?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, resize, window

I am developing a JFrame window with Swing and AWT, and when I resize the window, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, a lot of times when I resize the window, it shows a black rectangle where it is being resized and it doesn't go away until you pause for a moment. Additionally, the circle doesn't always update accurately with my resize event:

```
frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent componentEvent) {
        width = frame.getWidth();
        height = frame.getHeight();
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, panel, height, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame.getContentPane());
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, panel, width, SpringLayout.WEST, frame.getContentPane());
        panel.repaint();
    }
});
```

That's beside the point (though it is possible the two problems are linked). I have only ever encountered this problem when using Swing. JavaFX has never given me this problem. **Is there any way I can remove the black rectangle when the window is resized?**

Comment: You need to show more of your code. Like where to you override paintComponent().  And do not do the following:  1) extend JFrame, 2) Override Paint in JFrame().  You should create a JPanel and paint in that.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no good way to fix that problem.  Windows OS is responsible for managing many aspects of window resizing that can't be controlled from within Java.  My suggestion is to try calling "paintImmediately(...)" instead of "repaint()".  You could also set the background of the JFrame to white so it's not as noticeable.

Comment: Not sure why you are constantly updating the constraints. I would suggestion you can probably use a different layout manager, maybe the BorderLayout.

Comment: @WJS That is exactly what I do.

Comment: @camickr I update my constraints to make sure that the panel that has the circle is always as large as the window so that it never goes off-screen.

Comment: You need to show your code so we can help determine the problem.

Comment: *the circle is always as large as the window so that it never goes off-screen.* - which is exactly what the `BorderLayout` does and not constraints are necessary. Post your [mcve] if you need more help.

Answer (score 3):

*I have only tested this on Windows 10.*

This apparently has to do with the native window decorations of the window that hosts the JFrame. When disabling the native window decorations, you can remove the stuttering resizes and the black background bleeding through. See the documentation for `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(boolean)`:

> Provides a hint as to whether or not newly created JFrames should have their Window decorations (such as borders, widgets to close the window, title...) provided by the current look and feel. If defaultLookAndFeelDecorated is true, the current LookAndFeel supports providing window decorations, and the current window manager supports undecorated windows, then newly created JFrames will have their Window decorations provided by the current LookAndFeel. Otherwise, newly created JFrames will have their Window decorations provided by the current window manager.

Thus, you have two options. Either set the property once before you create your JFrame:

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

Or do it after the creation of the JFrame:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
```

Note that in either case, you are bound to use Swing's Look and Feel for the window decorations. The title bar and handles of the window are therefore going to look different than before.