# Black background on fast resizing a JFrame on windows

Tags: java, windows, swing

I started a new java project with netbeans, I created a `JFrame` then I launched my app then I noticed a black background that appears when resizing the window

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SimpleJFrameExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        // Set the size of the JFrame
        frame.setSize(400, 300);

        // Make the JFrame visible
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Set the default close operation when the user clicks the close button
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see there is a black backgroung that shows (in this case I', resizing to the right).

I found that :

> This apparently has to do with the native window decorations of the window that hosts the JFrame

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67043322/15160601) and it was proposing to use [`JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) .
I tried it and I got :

[image]

which works and doesn't show any background when resuzing but is not what I want my window to look like so I was wondering if there is
a way to stop this effect and keep the normal window decoration.

[image]

Comment: I don't see where I mentioned **fixing code**

Comment: I didn't metion something about fixing a code. I ask if there is a method or something in java to stop the delay that causes a black backgroud to be seen when resizing the frame,

Comment: Possibly related questions (although hard to say for sure without your [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code): [How to Remove Black Rectangle on Window Resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67043322/), and [How to eliminate black lag area in Java Swing running on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66382178/)

Comment: @camickr I will ask if it is possible that you copy my code and run it so you can have a better understanding of my problem.

Comment: I did try the posted code. There is nothing wrong with it other than my comment about creating components on the EDT. I tested on Windows 11 using JDK 11. *I started a new java project with netbeans,* - did you try to just compile/execute from the command line. Maybe something in your IDE is not set up correctly. Did you try reinstalling the IDE and JDK?  I have nothing else to offer since this is basic code.

Comment: I edited my post and added a gif, if you don't have the same problem so maybe it's a hardware problem

Comment: And once again the posted code doesn't match the gif. The gif includes a label. We can't trust anything your post.

Comment: Yes but the problem isn't related to the code

Comment: I took that gif from an unanswered question on stack overflow, the code has nothing to do with it, do you understand ?

Comment: Any image/gif you post should match the code you post so we know we are seeing the behaviour of the posted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I reduce this delay by setting a timer that revalidate and repaint the component every 100ms :
>
> ```
> resizeTimer = new Timer(100, (e) -> {
>        imagePanel.updateScaledImage();
>        revalidate();
>        repaint();
> });
> ```
>
> Is there a better way ?

Ahhh, I wouldn't be doing this constantly, if that's what you're doing, that's very expensive.

It is likely that `updateScaledImage` is blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing the UI from been painted until it completes OR your paint routine is blocking the Event Dispatching Thread during a paint pass, but that's all just guess work, as you've not provided a runnable example.

As stated, the likely cause is somewhere in your code, identifying it, is another issue.

What I've done in the past is used a "coalescing callback" coupled with a fast/low quality scaling approach.

This means, until there is a sufficient delay between resize events, I'd be using a fast/low quality scaling approach to render "something" to the screen.  Once a "sufficient delay" between resize events occurs, then I'd trigger a slow/high quality scale pass in a background thread, eventually updating the UI with this version.

Now remember, Swing is single threaded and NOT thread safe.  This means you shouldn't be executing blocking or long running operations within the Event Dispatching Thread and you shouldn't be updating the UI (or any state the UI relies on) from outside the Event Dispatching Thread.

To this end, I've made us of a Swing `Timer` (to act as my "coalescing callback" workflow) and a `SwingWorker` to perform the high quality scale.

[image]

*nb: The original image is 1920x1080. I'm also applying an `AlphaComposite` when the component is using the "fast scaling", so you can see when the "high quality" image becomes available.*

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/Mando01.jpeg"));
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new ImagePane(image));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {
        private Timer resizeTimer;
        private BufferedImage masterImage;
        private BufferedImage scaledImage;
        private Scaler scaler;

        public ImagePane(BufferedImage masterImage) {
            this.masterImage = masterImage;
            this.scaledImage = masterImage;

            scaler = new Scaler(masterImage);
            // This timer is "reset" each time the component is resized
            // This is an example of a "coalescing callback".  This means, rather
            // then responding to each resize event, which could cause a degradation
            // of the performance, we wait until no new events have occured with
            // a 250 millisecond period before we perform our action
            resizeTimer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
                private Object currentToken;
                // Adapter so we can extract the scaled image from the worker
                private SwingWorkerAdapter<ResizeWorker> workerAdapter = new SwingWorkerAdapter<>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void workerDone(ResizeWorker worker) {
                        try {
                            // The important part is the concept of the token
                            // Because we can't "stop" the worker, we need some
                            // to determine if we're interested in the results or
                            // not.  This uses a token based approach, but you
                            // could simply remove the adapter from the previous
                            // worker and apply it to the new worker
                            if (!worker.getToken().equals(currentToken)) {
                                return;
                            }
                            scaledImage = worker.get();
                            repaint();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                };

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // Just create something that is equatable and is relative
                    // unique within your context
                    currentToken = Instant.now();
                    // Offload the work to a background thread, so we can keep
                    // the UI responsive
                    ResizeWorker worker = new ResizeWorker(currentToken, scaler, getSize());
                    worker.addPropertyChangeListener(workerAdapter);
                    worker.execute();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            resizeTimer.setRepeats(false);
            addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                    scaledImage = null;
                    resizeTimer.restart();
                }
            });
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(scaledImage.getWidth(), scaledImage.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (scaledImage != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - scaledImage.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - scaledImage.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(scaledImage, x, y, this);
            } else {
                Dimension scaleSize = scaler.getScaledSizeToFill(getSize());
                int x = (getWidth() - scaleSize.width) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - scaleSize.height) / 2;
                // I've just applied a alpha composite so I can see when we're
                // do a "quick" render
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.1f));
                // This might not be the fastest method, but it is eaisly 
                // available
                g2d.drawImage(masterImage, x, y, scaleSize.width, scaleSize.height, this);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    // This makes it easier to deal with the PropertyChangeListener support of
    // SwingWorker and allows you to focus on only the states you are interested
    // in
    public class SwingWorkerAdapter<W extends SwingWorker> implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            W worker = (W) evt.getSource();
            switch (evt.getPropertyName()) {
                case "state":
                    workerStateChanged(worker);
                    switch (worker.getState()) {
                        case STARTED:
                            workerStarted(worker);
                            break;
                        case DONE:
                            workerDone(worker);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "progress":
                    workerProgressUpdated(worker);
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected void workerProgressUpdated(W worker) {
        }

        protected void workerStateChanged(W worker) {
        }

        protected void workerStarted(W worker) {
        }

        protected void workerDone(W worker) {
        }

    }

    // This SwingWorker performs the "quality" scaling workflow, which might
    // take some time to execute, so we do it in the background
    public class ResizeWorker extends SwingWorker<BufferedImage, BufferedImage> {
        private Object token;
        private Scaler scaler;
        private Dimension targetSize;

        public ResizeWorker(Object token, Scaler scaler, Dimension targetSize) {
            this.token = token;
            this.scaler = scaler;
            this.targetSize = targetSize;
        }

        public Object getToken() {
            return token;
        }

        @Override
        protected BufferedImage doInBackground() throws Exception {
            BufferedImage scaledImage = scaler.getScaledInstanceToFill(targetSize);
            publish(scaledImage);
            return scaledImage;
        }
    }

    // Utility class that uses a "divide and conqure" approach to the scaling
    // of images, this generally produces a higher quality image over using
    // Image#getScaledInstance in a single step
    public class Scaler {
        private BufferedImage master;
        private Dimension masterSize;

        private Map<RenderingHints.Key, Object> renderingHints = new HashMap<>();

        public Scaler(BufferedImage master) {
            this.master = master;
            masterSize = new Dimension(master.getWidth(), master.getHeight());
            renderingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            renderingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            renderingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            renderingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            renderingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            renderingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            renderingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            renderingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            renderingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
        }

        public BufferedImage getScaledInstanceToFit(Dimension size) {
            return getScaledInstance(getScaleFactorToFit(size));
        }

        public BufferedImage getScaledInstanceToFill(Dimension size) {
            return getScaledInstance(getScaleFactorToFill(size));
        }

        public Dimension getScaledSizeToFit(Dimension targetSize) {
            return getScaledSizeForScaleFactor(getScaleFactorToFit(targetSize));
        }

        public Dimension getScaledSizeToFill(Dimension targetSize) {
            return getScaledSizeForScaleFactor(getScaleFactorToFill(targetSize));
        }

        protected double getScaleFactor(int masterSize, int targetSize) {
            return (double) targetSize / (double) masterSize;
        }

        protected double getScaleFactorToFit(Dimension toFit) {
            double dScaleWidth = getScaleFactor(masterSize.width, toFit.width);
            double dScaleHeight = getScaleFactor(masterSize.height, toFit.height);
            return Math.min(dScaleHeight, dScaleWidth);
        }

        protected double getScaleFactorToFill(Dimension targetSize) {
            double dScaleWidth = getScaleFactor(masterSize.width, targetSize.width);
            double dScaleHeight = getScaleFactor(masterSize.height, targetSize.height);
            return Math.max(dScaleHeight, dScaleWidth);
        }

        protected Dimension getScaledSizeForScaleFactor(double scaleFactor) {
            int targetWidth = (int) Math.round(masterSize.getWidth() * scaleFactor);
            int targetHeight = (int) Math.round(masterSize.getHeight() * scaleFactor);
            return new Dimension(targetWidth, targetHeight);
        }

        protected BufferedImage getScaledInstance(double dScaleFactor) {
            BufferedImage imgScale = master;
            int targetWidth = (int) Math.round(masterSize.getWidth() * dScaleFactor);
            int targetHeight = (int) Math.round(masterSize.getHeight() * dScaleFactor);

            if (dScaleFactor <= 1.0d) {
                imgScale = getScaledDownInstance(targetWidth, targetHeight);
            } else {
                imgScale = getScaledUpInstance(targetWidth, targetHeight);
            }

            return imgScale;
        }

        protected BufferedImage getScaledDownInstance(
                int targetWidth,
                int targetHeight) {

            int type = (master.getTransparency() == Transparency.OPAQUE)
                    ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;

            BufferedImage scaled = master;

            if (targetHeight > 0 || targetWidth > 0) {
                int width = master.getWidth();
                int height = master.getHeight();

                do {
                    if (width > targetWidth) {
                        width /= 2;
                        if (width < targetWidth) {
                            width = targetWidth;
                        }
                    }
                    if (height > targetHeight) {
                        height /= 2;
                        if (height < targetHeight) {
                            height = targetHeight;
                        }
                    }

                    BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(Math.max(width, 1), Math.max(height, 1), type);
                    Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
                    g2.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
                    g2.drawImage(scaled, 0, 0, width, height, null);
                    g2.dispose();

                    scaled = tmp;
                } while (width != targetWidth || height != targetHeight);
            } else {
                scaled = new BufferedImage(1, 1, type);
            }

            return scaled;
        }

        protected BufferedImage getScaledUpInstance(
                int targetWidth,
                int targetHeight) {

            int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;

            BufferedImage ret = (BufferedImage) master;
            int width = master.getWidth();
            int height = master.getHeight();

            do {
                if (width < targetWidth) {
                    width *= 2;
                    if (width > targetWidth) {
                        width = targetWidth;
                    }
                }

                if (height < targetHeight) {
                    height *= 2;
                    if (height > targetHeight) {
                        height = targetHeight;
                    }
                }

                BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
                Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
                g2.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
                g2.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, width, height, null);
                g2.dispose();

                ret = tmp;
            } while (width != targetWidth || height != targetHeight);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Please beware, this is just one implementation of the described approach, you might find a different way to implement which better fits your own needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not the problem here

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my fault, the problem wasn't asked well, again thank you so much for your answer and the effort you put to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a Toolkit property that causes the behaviour you describe:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleJFrameExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDynamicLayout(false);

        // Create a new JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        // Set the size of the JFrame
        frame.setSize(400, 300);

        // Make the JFrame visible
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Set the default close operation when the user clicks the close button
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

If I change it back to "true" the issue goes away:

```
//Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDynamicLayout(false);
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDynamicLayout(true);
```

Don't know how or where this property might be set to "false" by default.

Comment: I added that to my code and my problem was solved, then I decided to remove it from my code but the problem wasn't there, that's weird, I think it was a problem with my hardware.

Comment: It is a hardware problem, I restarted my computer and the flicktering came back even with your code, it might be because on startup the cpu is too busy.

Comment: If you have random problems, as I have mention multiple times before, all GUI components should be created on the `EDT`. Whether this fixes the problem or not you should be doing this for any code you write.